# How does pulling back on the yoke make you recover from a flat spin

Tags: general-aviation

One method I read here, to recover from a flat spin, is to pull back on the yoke or stick, which would push the tail down when facing to the back, and up a bit when facing forward. I assume, if the plane as a whole, acts like a spinning top, it would be like tapping a spinning disc up on the side facing the oncoming air and down on the side facing back. That, with the gyroscopic effect should tip the plane sideways (to the right out of a LH spin) is that correct?

Comment: Please see if the following are helpful: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46935/what-is-the-procedure-to-enter-maintain-and-recover-from-a-flat-spin or https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/is-it-possible-to-recover-from-a-flat-spin/2211#2211

Comment: @Ralph J Thanks! Rather than tipping the plane, the methods seem to be about coutering the spin by trying to spin the plane the other way, either by the rudder, or by using the ailerons to make the plane act like a windmill, making use of the updraught as the plane falls.